# Connecting to Samba shares from a Windows 7 SP1 machine

Tags: windows-7, networking, network-shares, samba

I have just configured a Ubuntu server at home, which I have named CRICHTON, running Samba 3.6.3, and created a test share, named Media.  Sadly, I can't connect to it from my Windows 7 SP1 machine.  I have changed the LAN Manager authentication level to "Send LM & NTLM - use NTLMv2 session security if negotiated" which seems to have helped a lot of people, but to no avail.

I'm on a home network, and I can cheerfully ssh into my server.  I can even see the server and shared folder in an Explorer window.  I've managed to achieve some success by creating a workgroup, joining it and identifying it in the samba config file, but then only read-only access seems available, and anyway WITHOUT authentication of some kind it's not much use.  Right now, without workgroup shenanigans, as soon as I try to open a share I am asked for a login.  Particularly, I am asked:

> Enter Network Password
>
> Enter your password to connect to: CRICHTON

I enter my user name and password, which is the same as my Samba user name and password.  Then the login repeats itself, only this time it prepends my username with the name of my machine, only allowing me to submit a password.

Unfortunately my Windows Networking knowledge is poor.  Does anyone have any clues?  Is there a step-by-step guide to connecting to Samba from Windows 7 out there somewhere?  I've found one that ignores security issues, but that isn't appropriate here.

Comment: In /etc/smb.conf  There is a line "Security = " what is after the equal sign?  What kind of password database is it set to? tdbsam,passwd, or other?  Try using the samba add user command to see if that helps.   **smbpasswd -a username**  
After setting a password try again.

Comment: Whoops the location could also be /etc/samba/smb.conf

Comment: security = user
passdb backend = tdbsam

Several users already added, none working :-(  Thanks for your help!

Comment: In smb.conf   find  **[Media]**  Is one of the entries **read only = No **  another good entry is **Browseable = yes** additionally:  **write list = <list of usernames here>**

Comment: Additionally you need to restart the nmb and smb samba services after making changes to smb.conf

Comment: I seem to have access to the folders now, without being a workgroup member, but I still can't write to them.  write list was new information, thanks!

Comment: When you say access to the folders, which folders because so far we have only dicussed **[Media]** which is a single folder or are you referring to the subfolders under **[Media]**?  It would be easier if you would post the content of the **[Media]** and **[global]** sections.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/12216/discussion-between-guy-davidson-and-cybernard)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cybernard was able to walk me through this.  There were several things wrong, but particularly the share directory was created with unhelpful permissions, the user I was connecting as wasn't a member of the appropriate group, and I hadn't created a write list for the share.

Clearly there is a lot of brittleness between Samba, Linux and Windows 7.

Comment: please write out how to make it work as a single post so the comments can be deleted

Comment: Sorry endolith, this was three years ago and I don't have records of the conversation. It took several hours, I can tell you that, and several iterations of conversations. The comments above were only scratching the surface: the discussion in chat was where the revelations were.